# Is Suspend (S3) supported on the Nexus 7?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

I was curious to know if suspend was supported on the Nexus 7, the tablet will suspend from the system indicator but there seems to be a problem when attempting to suspend via the power menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suspend is currently supported from the system indicator. However, it does not currently work from the power menu, as there is an [upstream bug here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-session/+bug/1041137):